# Widen some columns in a table

Tags: tables

I would like to make the columns Valpha and Vbeta in voltage output wider while reducing the width of the Voltage N° column. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
%\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip} % Baseline skip between items
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c| p{0.6cm} | p{0.6cm}| p{0.6cm} | p{1.0cm}| p{1.0cm} | c | 
c } \hline \hline
\multicolumn 1 {c|}{Voltage $N^{\circ}$} &
\multicolumn {3} {c|}{\centering Switching states } &
\multicolumn 2 {c|}{Voltage output} &
\multicolumn 1 {c|}{Magnitude} &
\multicolumn 1 {c}{Phase} \\   \hline \hline
$V_n$ & \centering$S_a$ &\centering $ S_b$ & \centering$ S_c$ & $\: \: \: 
\:V_{\alpha}$ & $\: \: \: \:V_{\beta}$ & $U_{ref}$ & $\alpha$ \\ \hline
$V_{1p}$  &  \centering 1 & \centering 0 & \centering 0 & $U_{dc}$/3  
&\centering0 & $U_{dc}$/3 & 0 \\
$V_{1n}$  &  \centering 0 & \centering -1 & \centering -1 & $U_{dc}$/3  
&\centering0 & $U_{dc}$/3 & 0 \\
$V_{2p}$  &  \centering 1 & \centering 1 & \centering 0 & $U_{dc}$/6  
&\centering$\sqrt{3}$ $\frac{U_{dc}}{6}$  & $U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi/3$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

As you can see from the figure below I couldn't write all the expression in the last line  Vbeta

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're using fixed width for columns; just increase the allotted space for the ones you need.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to simplify your table code drastically by defining a centered version of the `p` column type. And, since you're loading the `booktabs` package, I would also like to suggest that you use its macros to give the table a much more open and reader-friendly look.

[image]

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}

\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
%%\usepackage{caption} % is loaded automatically by 'subcaption'
\usepackage{lscape,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % centered 'p' col.
%%\usepackage{natbib} % is loaded automatically by elsarticle doc class
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed}  % Framing content
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

%% Load the next two packages *last*:
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} c *{3}{C{0.6cm}} *{2}{C{1.5cm}} c c @{}} 
\toprule
Voltage N\textsuperscript{o} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Switching states} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Voltage output} & Magnitude & Phase \\   
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
$V_n$ & $S_a$ & $S_b$ & $S_c$ & $V_{\alpha}$ & $V_{\beta}$ & $U_{\mathrm{ref}}$ & $\alpha$ \\ 
\midrule
$V_{1p}$ & 1 & 0    & 0    & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0                    & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0 \\
$V_{1n}$ & 0 & $-1$ & $-1$ & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0                    & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0 \\
$V_{2p}$ & 1 & 1    & 0    & $U_{dc}/6$ & $\sqrt{3}\,U_{dc}/6$ & $U_{dc}/3$ & $\pi/3$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```